# Smart cast after type check inside takeIf function

Tags: kotlin, types, casting, functional-programming

I have this Kotlin code:

```
interface Course
class ProgrammingCourse : Course
class MathCourse : Course

...

fun doSomething(id: String) = getCourse(id)
    .takeIf { it is ProgrammingCourse }
    .apply {
      //do something with the course
    }
}

fun getCourse(id: String) : Course {
    //fetch course
}
```

Inside `apply` function, `this` is of type `Course?`, it should be `ProgrammingCourse?`, isn't it? Smart cast is not working in this case.

I guess Kotlin doesn't support this yet. Is there a way to make this work, without using `if/else`, I mean, in a function chaining way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just solved using `as?` operator, that casts to `ProgrammingCourse` or returns `null` on error:

```
fun doSomething(id: String) = getCourse(id)
    .let { it as? ProgrammingCourse }
    ?.apply {
      //do something with the course
    }
}
```

Now, inside `apply` function, `this` is of type `ProgrammingCourse` (non-nullable, because of `?`)